# How to fill in a space with white color in Paint.NET?

Tags: paint.net

I have dozens of image files with charts. The charts have Russian legends to them. I need to quickly remove the Russian legends and print in the English versions. When I select a rectangular area including the Russian legend and press Delete, I get this:

> [image]

I now need to select the color white, use the bucket tool to pour white over the checkered area, and then select the color black and select the Text tool and print in the English language version of the chart title.

Is there a way to delete an area and to make it white, not checkered, at the same time, in one operation? I hate to do all these operations by hand over and over again.

Is there some other tool besides Paint.NET for quickly and easily replacing text in images?

Answer (score 2):

It's showing you the checkerboard because your image has a transparent background.

Add a white layer behind the layer you're deleting from, that way when you delete something from your layer, the white on the layer below is what will show.

Comment: Sadly, a newly-created layer is transparent by definition. Thus, I need to create it, then to "select all", then select the bucket tool, then select the color white, then pour it in, to make the new layer white. All this results in more work..

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to choose the Shapes tool > Rectangle > Draw filled shape,
where the fore-color is set to white.

Then just paint over the areas you wish to be white.

Or you may use the back-color to draw the white rectangles and the fore-color
for another color.